# How can I copy MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I want to copy my database that I've created in order to submit the code to my teacher, but I don't know where is my database located?

Comment: Try Google : "mysql copy table". You should find some links very useful

Comment: How did you install the database...?

Comment: just backup your database,it will generate backup file and give that your teacher

Comment: Even if you knew where yourdatabase is located, copying the files probably won't help. Take a look at [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that your teacher has already told you this but there is a [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) tool specifically for this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasenametobackup > file.db
```

and to restore:

```
mysql -u root -p databasetorestoreto < file.db
```

Answer (score 0):

or, if you are using xampp, just open your browser then type "localhost" and GUI of xampp will appear. and then, try to find "export button" and click it. it seems like download any file from any sites you ever did

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have the MYSQL GUI tool use this

for a single table

```
SELECT * FROM sample_tbl 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/sample.txt'; //path where you want to extract the table
```

for entire database

```
mysqldump -u root -p Database1 > database_dump.db
password ******
```

To restore copy the file to destination and run this command

```
mysql -u root -p databasetorestoreto < database_dump.db
```

If you have the GUI tool you can directly do that from the menu. Backup your db in an out file copy it to machine and restore it again .